# Is there integer functions $f(n), g(n)$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)\zeta(2) + g(n) = 0$

Tags: number-theory

Is there integer functions $f(n)$ and  $g(n)$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)\zeta(2) + g(n) = 0$ where $f(n)\zeta(2) + g(n) \neq 0$ for all positive integer $n$.

For example:

$(-1)^n!n e + (-1)^{n+1}n! \neq 0$ for all positive integer $n$ and the limit at infinity is $0$. Here $f(n) = (-1)^n!n$ and $g(n) = (-1)^{n+1}n!$ are integers functions for all positive integer $n$. Instead of $e$ I want to use $\zeta(2)$.

Comment: Equivalently, you want $\zeta(2) \approx -g(n)/f(n)$ where $g$ and $f$ are integers. There are arbitrarily good rational approximations, and so the answer is "yes" to your question.

Comment: @davidlowryduda $\zeta(2) +g(n)/f(n)=o(1/f(n))$ is much stronger than $\zeta(2) +g(n)/f(n)=o(1)$

Answer (score 2):

For any real number $x$, there exist functions $f,g$ so that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} xf(n)+g(n)=0.$$

If $x$ is rational, then this is trivial. Otherwise, let $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be the $n$th convergent to the continued fraction of $x$, and let $g(n)=-p_n$, $f(n)=q_n$.

For more about continued fraction convergents, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents).

Comment: It's possible that these $f,g$ are integer valued functions for all integer $n$? If so, how to find they?

Comment: @Pinteco Yes, continued fraction convergents are always integers, as they're all about approximating real numbers by rational numbers. I've added a link about them in my answer.